# pgsql master slave replication error on different versions

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to replicate postgresql 10 as master server in ubuntu 18.04 LTS to postgresql 9.5 slave server in ubuntu 16.04 but got the error

```
postgres@localhost:/root$ pg_basebackup -h 139.162.4.197 -U replication -p 5432 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/  -Fp -Xs -P -R

could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
Password: 
pg_basebackup: incompatible server version 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

but when done with same postgresql versions like

- postgresql 10 as master and postgresql 10 slave or
- postgresql 12 as master and postgresql 12 slave

it replicates fine

but when done with different postgresql version like

- postgresql 10 as master and postgresql 9.5 slave or
- postgresql 12 as master and postgresql 10 slave

I got the above error

> pg_basebackup: incompatible server version 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-1.pgdg18.04+1)

any clues to resolve the issue

Comment: This is not possible. Streaming replication only works between the same major versions (and operating systems). If you need to replicate between different major versions, you need to use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) (but it's not available in the [unsupported version](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) 9.5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have a reference?  I haven't been able to find anything in the changelog or replication info yet.

Comment: @AllanWind: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-PLANNING) - "*log shipping between servers running different major PostgreSQL release levels is not possible*" (and streaming replication is essntially based on log shipping)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with streaming replication; the horse's comment quotes [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-PLANNING):

> In general, log shipping between servers running different major PostgreSQL release levels is not possible.

But from PostgreSQL v10 on you could use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html), which also works between major releases. The problem with that is that not everything is replicated: DDL statements are not.